# .htaccess Remove URL Extension, Add Trailing Slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I have been trying to get this to work on my client's server for a website I am developing, but I simply cannot get it to work. Basically I am trying to remove the .html extensions, and add a trailing slash (in the URL bar).

So if someone enters:

-example.com/home/ ----------- goes to ----- example.com/home/

-example.com/home ------------ goes to ----- example.com/home/

-example.com/home.html ------ goes to ----- example.com/home/

-example.com/home.html/ ----- goes to ----- example.com/home/

-example.com/home/.html ----- goes to ----- example.com/home/

-example.com/home/.html/ ---- goes to ----- example.com/home/

Here is my .htaccess so far, which works PERFECTLY, and does everything I want it do, except add the trailing slash at the end.

Here is that code:

```
#force www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/1 [R=301,L]

# remove .html ONLY if requested directly
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (\.html\sHTTP/1)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html /1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# remove trailing slash ONLY if it is not an existing folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ /1 [L,R=301]

# rewrite to FILENAME.html if such file does exist and is not a folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /1.html [L,QSA]
```

All of my files hosted on the server are in the form of FILENAME.html, and are located in the root directory.

So, if any one could please help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

## Modify the .htaccess file and insert the following

Explanation: 
http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2007/08/19/removing-file-extension-via-htaccess/

Example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

## Update the links on the pages

Then, all hyperlinks, css links, images, etc, will need to be updated to have either an absolute URL (`http://www.site.com/style.css`) or relative and begin with `../`.  Otherwise you will encounter issues such as CSS that doesn't load, links that don't work, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried that solution, and it does not work for me at all.  I just get an error 404 not found page.  The .htaccess I posted in the OP works perfectly, it just doesn't add the slash on the end of the URL.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try this one, it's a little more clear.

Comment: That doesn't work for me either.  It adds the slash, but doesn't load any CSS, or images for that matter.  On top of that, when I click on any links on my site it just adds them to whatever is in the URL bar.  Let's say I am on example.com/home/ and then I click test, then instead of going to example.com/test/ it goes to example.com/home/test.

Comment: Your links, CSS, images,etc, all need to be absolute or relative but beginning with "../"

Comment: I understand, but the .htaccess file still doesn't work.  Like I said, it just adds the link to the end of whatever the URL of the page is on when it is clicked.  The code that I have in the first post works perfectly, but it doesn't add the slash.  How could I modify that code to just add the slash at the end?

Comment: Do you have a sample page I can see?  All links, CSS, images, etc should be the full absolute path i.e. `http://www.site.com/style.css` otherwise you'll encounter the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I changed the .htaccess to the code you posted and it adds a slash if I type in the URL without the .html extension, but if I type it in with the .html extension it still shows it.  I would like the .html extension to automatically disappear and then add a slash.