# .htaccess remove .html

Tags: html, .htaccess

I realize there is another post about how to remove .html but it is not working for me so I am trying to understand a little better how this process works.

I have fatcow for my hosting service.  I downloaded the .htaccess from fatcow and it downloaded at a .htm file.  I inserted this code via notepad.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

 </IfModule>
```

I saved the file as .htaccess and uploaded it to my root folder on fatcow.  It is now saved in my root folder as .htaccess.txt

What am I doing wrong here to where this is not working?

UPDATE:

I renamed the .htaccess.txt to .htaccess via FTP client.  It shows up at .htaccess now but it is still not removing the .html from my urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be saved as `.htaccess`, not `.htaccess.txt`.

It might be named this way because you created the file on Windows. If this is the case, you have two options:

### Upload, then rename

Once the file is uploaded to the server, you can most likely rename the file to have the correct name.

### Rename, then upload

You can rename it by doing the following in the Command Prompt:

```
cd C:\Directory\With\File\In\It
rename .htaccess.txt .htaccess
```

Once that is done, it should be named `.htaccess` properly, and can be uploaded.

Comment: I figured that but it won't let me change the .txt on fatcow.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: What ways do you have for uploading the file?

Comment: Are you using FTP? Can you not just right-click on the file and rename it? If not maybe give the Fatcow support folks an email/call?

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: If the file manager doesn't let you rename the file, then try FTP.

Comment: No, shoudn't make a difference. But you definitely can't rename it?

Comment: I renamed it using FTP.  I went to look at my webpages and they still display the .html

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: And if you access the page without the .html in the filename, does it work then? Do you want it to redirect .html-urls to non-.html-urls?

Comment: @Sebastian it will show the page but with no css styles applied to it

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: See the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9963676/79061

Comment: @Sebastian How do you rename the files to those paths when windows doesn't accept that?

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: I'm not sure what you're asking me?

Comment: @Sebastian I apologize I misunderstood them.  I understand now.  Thanks for your help